# Missing dimensions

Tags: r, dimensions, panel-data, plm

I'm a new R user and I'm trying to use panel data (fixed effects) to analyse the effect that several independent variables have on the log of GNI. I'm using the plm package, and this is my code

```r
library(plm)
head(project_data)

Y = cbind(project_data$log_GNI_PPP)
X = cbind(project_data$EU_application, project_data$EU_membership,
          project_data$distance_from_brussels, project_data$Former_USSR_DUMMY,
          project_data$natural_resources_pct,
          project_data$secondary_attendence_prct,
          project_data$eu_education_interaction)

project_data_panel = pdata.frame(project_data, index = c("country_name", "year"))
plm(Y ~ X, data = project_data_panel, model = "within")
```

However, when I do this get the error

> Error in class(x) <- setdiff(class(x), "pseries") :
>         invalid to set the class to matrix unless the dimension attribute is of length 2 (was 0)

I'm not sure as this means, as X,Y and project_data_panel all seem to have the correct dimensions (812 x   6) (812 x 1) and (812 x 16) respectively. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Here's an example of the data

```
    dput(head(project_data, 50))
```

```
structure(list(country_name = c("Albania", "Albania", "Albania", 
"Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", 
"Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", 
"Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", 
"Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", 
"Albania", "Albania", "Armenia", "Armenia", "Armenia", "Armenia", 
"Armenia", "Armenia", "Armenia", "Armenia", "Armenia", "Armenia", 
"Armenia", "Armenia", "Armenia", "Armenia", "Armenia", "Armenia", 
"Armenia", "Armenia", "Armenia", "Armenia", "Armenia"), `Country Code` = c("ALB", 
"ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", 
"ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", 
"ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", 
"ALB", "ARM", "ARM", "ARM", "ARM", "ARM", "ARM", "ARM", "ARM", 
"ARM", "ARM", "ARM", "ARM", "ARM", "ARM", "ARM", "ARM", "ARM", 
"ARM", "ARM", "ARM", "ARM"), year = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 
1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
2016, 2017, 2018, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 
1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 
2009, 2010), EU_application = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), EU_membership = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), distance_from_brussels = c(1589, 1589, 
1589, 1589, 1589, 1589, 1589, 1589, 1589, 1589, 1589, 1589, 1589, 
1589, 1589, 1589, 1589, 1589, 1589, 1589, 1589, 1589, 1589, 1589, 
1589, 1589, 1589, 1589, 1589, 3300, 3300, 3300, 3300, 3300, 3300, 
3300, 3300, 3300, 3300, 3300, 3300, 3300, 3300, 3300, 3300, 3300, 
3300, 3300, 3300, 3300), GNI_PPP_per_cap = c(2550, 1870, 1730, 
2120, 2310, 2710, 3050, 2780, 3110, 3550, 3980, 4460, 4800, 5150, 
5560, 5990, 6750, 7480, 8260, 8670, 9530, 10210, 10450, 10750, 
11360, 11800, 12060, 12960, 13350, 2340, 2240, 1130, 1190, 1430, 
1590, 1790, 1960, 2090, 2200, 2390, 2700, 3140, 3660, 4160, 4970, 
5870, 6970, 7700, 6590, 6890), GNI_PPP_GROWTH = c(NA, "-36.36%", 
"-8.09%", "18.40%", "8.23%", "14.76%", "11.15%", "-9.71%", "10.61%", 
"12.39%", "10.80%", "10.76%", "7.08%", "6.80%", "7.37%", "7.18%", 
"11.26%", "9.76%", "9.44%", "4.73%", "9.02%", "6.66%", "2.30%", 
"2.79%", "5.37%", "3.73%", "2.16%", "6.94%", "2.92%", NA, "-4.27%", 
"-49.55%", "5.31%", "20.17%", "11.19%", "12.58%", "9.50%", "6.63%", 
"5.26%", "8.64%", "12.97%", "16.30%", "16.56%", "13.66%", "19.47%", 
"18.11%", "18.74%", "10.47%", "-14.42%", "4.55%"), Stability_Index = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, 8, 9, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 9, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7), Former_USSR_DUMMY = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `Tertiary_enrollment rate` = c("8.3663600000000002", 
"8.8553300000000004", "9.2873199999999994", "11.17761", "10.63358", 
"10.202819999999999", "10.939450000000001", "12.699719999999999", 
"13.55017", "14.747769999999999", "15.53661", "15.904629999999999", 
"16.311430000000001", "16.657240000000002", "19.890440000000002", 
"23.189830000000001", "26.637139999999999", "30.68713", "32.092799999999997", 
"33.385550000000002", "44.549250000000001", "49.878700000000002", 
"59.252009999999999", "64.634429999999995", "65.782970000000006", 
"62.007620000000003", "58.38185", "57.375259999999997", "54.961329999999997", 
"23.204820000000002", "25.3567", "25.342120000000001", "23.027640000000002", 
"19.124310000000001", "19.082139999999999", "16.938569999999999", 
"22.720230000000001", "33.57358", "35.212409999999998", "35.549790000000002", 
"33.545299999999997", "36.146859999999997", "37.218879999999999", 
"37.883139999999997", "39.546770000000002", "43.115349999999999", 
"45.93094", "48.489330000000002", "51.334589999999999", "52.989150000000002"
), `Trade Openess` = c(39.4369634, 36.07052006, 108.7854722, 
80.51833277, 53.10258474, 47.61059487, 44.89542726, 45.42552335, 
48.13748354, 51.01107175, 63.4540744, 66.49104645, 68.52503792, 
67.02060851, 67.04722821, 70.87232827, 74.26708173, 83.20210079, 
77.45174863, 75.09481856, 76.54335524, 81.21856394, 76.51020102, 
75.87373278, 75.40786559, 71.80103037, 74.80985622, 78.16131198, 
77.08240186, 81.33571855, 100.8658552, 101.0767594, 107.9731463, 
112.4293646, 86.11485707, 79.22956012, 78.54774505, 71.84245188, 
70.56047914, 73.91851927, 71.61719663, 75.94344895, 82.18767117, 
75.03721018, 72.03895668, 62.60919306, 58.33644568, 55.70286492, 
58.47886987, 66.14730981), natural_resources_pct = c(11.05002975, 
9.344824468, 11.41790163, 2.804094484, 1.738143406, 1.28764727, 
1.334614417, 1.37003297, 0.304234074, 0.568541328, 1.094738792, 
0.732501135, 0.755764016, 0.762078498, 0.776381057, 1.050084705, 
1.431007073, 2.171629466, 1.629199242, 0.98009147, 2.033752543, 
3.455044143, 3.596119659, 3.578365186, 3.574896619, 1.813210471, 
1.049502751, 1.698859222, NA, 0, 0, 0.105584847, 0.102698623, 
0.468567478, 0.731881752, 0.511241769, 0.551497144, 0.160976758, 
0.141442386, 0.363203884, 0.29675514, 0.460041922, 0.520673274, 
0.974003626, 0.901240752, 1.788861711, 1.297061299, 1.294545673, 
1.656635559, 2.992128557), Tertiary_enrollment_rate_prop = c(0.0836636, 
0.0885533, 0.0928732, 0.1117761, 0.1063358, 0.1020282, 0.1093945, 
0.1269972, 0.1355017, 0.1474777, 0.1553661, 0.1590463, 0.1631143, 
0.1665724, 0.1989044, 0.2318983, 0.2663714, 0.3068713, 0.320928, 
0.3338555, 0.4454925, 0.498787, 0.5925201, 0.6463443, 0.6578297, 
0.6200762, 0.5838185, 0.5737526, 0.5496133, 0.2320482, 0.253567, 
0.2534212, 0.2302764, 0.1912431, 0.1908214, 0.1693857, 0.2272023, 
0.3357358, 0.3521241, 0.3554979, 0.335453, 0.3614686, 0.3721888, 
0.3788314, 0.3954677, 0.4311535, 0.4593094, 0.4848933, 0.5133459, 
0.5298915), log_GNI_PPP = c(7.84384863815247, 7.53369370984863, 
7.45587668749182, 7.65917136766606, 7.74500280351584, 7.90470391387375, 
8.02289686960146, 7.93020620668468, 8.04237800517328, 8.17470288246946, 
8.28903709827848, 8.40290404501411, 8.47637119689598, 8.54675199365778, 
8.62335338724463, 8.6978466911095, 8.81729778386658, 8.91998807096852, 
9.01917986651502, 9.06762406977459, 9.16219999664825, 9.23112291115871, 
9.25435725739296, 9.28266103355581, 9.33785369227514, 9.37585481045376, 
9.39764947028118, 9.46962296990626, 9.4992716638284, 7.75790620835175, 
7.71423114484909, 7.02997291170639, 7.08170858610557, 7.26542972325395, 
7.37148929521428, 7.4899708988348, 7.58069975222456, 7.64491934495886, 
7.69621263934641, 7.77904864492556, 7.90100705199242, 8.0519780789023, 
8.20521842639541, 8.33327035325531, 8.51117511909067, 8.67760991282214, 
8.84937050375457, 8.94897560784178, 8.79330862749655, 8.8378263640077
), secondary_attendence_prct = c(90.08174, 90.89363, 77.71476, 
70.33512, 68.72906, 68.67849, 67.86755, 69.36618, 71.31361, 71.54467, 
71.07808, 72.53716, 72.86855, 75.24344, 74.80221, 77.90939, 79.18955, 
82.20059, 84.12509, 85.69499, 88.10389, 89.79816, 92.28983, 96.25608, 
97.68487, 97.38848, 95.715, 95.26589, 95.43233, NA, 92.10371, 
92.32686, 94.7447, 96.62907, NA, 93.3364, 93.23616, 80.43603, 
80.05668, 92.15199, 88.28202, NA, NA, 89.34573, 92.05428, 94.94133, 
96.42764, 94.97048, 100.12562, 104.71332)), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here it is just using head

```
    head(project_data_panel, 50)
```

```
             country_name Country Code year EU_application EU_membership
Albania-1990      Albania          ALB 1990              0             0
Albania-1991      Albania          ALB 1991              0             0
Albania-1992      Albania          ALB 1992              0             0
Albania-1993      Albania          ALB 1993              0             0
Albania-1994      Albania          ALB 1994              0             0
Albania-1995      Albania          ALB 1995              0             0
Albania-1996      Albania          ALB 1996              0             0
Albania-1997      Albania          ALB 1997              0             0
Albania-1998      Albania          ALB 1998              0             0
Albania-1999      Albania          ALB 1999              0             0
Albania-2000      Albania          ALB 2000              0             0
Albania-2001      Albania          ALB 2001              0             0
Albania-2002      Albania          ALB 2002              0             0
Albania-2003      Albania          ALB 2003              0             0
Albania-2004      Albania          ALB 2004              0             0
Albania-2005      Albania          ALB 2005              0             0
Albania-2006      Albania          ALB 2006              0             0
Albania-2007      Albania          ALB 2007              0             0
Albania-2008      Albania          ALB 2008              0             0
Albania-2009      Albania          ALB 2009              1             0
Albania-2010      Albania          ALB 2010              1             0
Albania-2011      Albania          ALB 2011              1             0
Albania-2012      Albania          ALB 2012              1             0
Albania-2013      Albania          ALB 2013              1             0
Albania-2014      Albania          ALB 2014              1             0
Albania-2015      Albania          ALB 2015              1             0
Albania-2016      Albania          ALB 2016              1             0
Albania-2017      Albania          ALB 2017              1             0
Albania-2018      Albania          ALB 2018              1             0
Armenia-1990      Armenia          ARM 1990              0             0
Armenia-1991      Armenia          ARM 1991              0             0
Armenia-1992      Armenia          ARM 1992              0             0
Armenia-1993      Armenia          ARM 1993              0             0
Armenia-1994      Armenia          ARM 1994              0             0
Armenia-1995      Armenia          ARM 1995              0             0
Armenia-1996      Armenia          ARM 1996              0             0
Armenia-1997      Armenia          ARM 1997              0             0
Armenia-1998      Armenia          ARM 1998              0             0
Armenia-1999      Armenia          ARM 1999              0             0
Armenia-2000      Armenia          ARM 2000              0             0
Armenia-2001      Armenia          ARM 2001              0             0
Armenia-2002      Armenia          ARM 2002              0             0
Armenia-2003      Armenia          ARM 2003              0             0
Armenia-2004      Armenia          ARM 2004              0             0
Armenia-2005      Armenia          ARM 2005              0             0
Armenia-2006      Armenia          ARM 2006              0             0
Armenia-2007      Armenia          ARM 2007              0             0
Armenia-2008      Armenia          ARM 2008              0             0
Armenia-2009      Armenia          ARM 2009              0             0
Armenia-2010      Armenia          ARM 2010              0             0
             distance_from_brussels GNI_PPP_per_cap GNI_PPP_GROWTH Stability_Index
Albania-1990                   1589            2550           <NA>              NA
Albania-1991                   1589            1870        -36.36%              NA
Albania-1992                   1589            1730         -8.09%              NA
Albania-1993                   1589            2120         18.40%              NA
Albania-1994                   1589            2310          8.23%              NA
Albania-1995                   1589            2710         14.76%               8
Albania-1996                   1589            3050         11.15%               8
Albania-1997                   1589            2780         -9.71%               9
Albania-1998                   1589            3110         10.61%               8
Albania-1999                   1589            3550         12.39%               7
Albania-2000                   1589            3980         10.80%               7
Albania-2001                   1589            4460         10.76%               7
Albania-2002                   1589            4800          7.08%               7
Albania-2003                   1589            5150          6.80%               7
Albania-2004                   1589            5560          7.37%               7
Albania-2005                   1589            5990          7.18%               5
Albania-2006                   1589            6750         11.26%               5
Albania-2007                   1589            7480          9.76%               4
Albania-2008                   1589            8260          9.44%               3
Albania-2009                   1589            8670          4.73%               3
Albania-2010                   1589            9530          9.02%               3
Albania-2011                   1589           10210          6.66%               3
Albania-2012                   1589           10450          2.30%               2
Albania-2013                   1589           10750          2.79%               3
Albania-2014                   1589           11360          5.37%               2
Albania-2015                   1589           11800          3.73%               2
Albania-2016                   1589           12060          2.16%               2
Albania-2017                   1589           12960          6.94%               1
Albania-2018                   1589           13350          2.92%               1
Armenia-1990                   3300            2340           <NA>              NA
Armenia-1991                   3300            2240         -4.27%              NA
Armenia-1992                   3300            1130        -49.55%              NA
Armenia-1993                   3300            1190          5.31%              NA
Armenia-1994                   3300            1430         20.17%              NA
Armenia-1995                   3300            1590         11.19%               8
Armenia-1996                   3300            1790         12.58%               7
Armenia-1997                   3300            1960          9.50%               8
Armenia-1998                   3300            2090          6.63%               8
Armenia-1999                   3300            2200          5.26%               8
Armenia-2000                   3300            2390          8.64%               8
Armenia-2001                   3300            2700         12.97%               9
Armenia-2002                   3300            3140         16.30%               7
Armenia-2003                   3300            3660         16.56%               7
Armenia-2004                   3300            4160         13.66%               7
Armenia-2005                   3300            4970         19.47%               7
Armenia-2006                   3300            5870         18.11%               7
Armenia-2007                   3300            6970         18.74%               6
Armenia-2008                   3300            7700         10.47%               6
Armenia-2009                   3300            6590        -14.42%               7
Armenia-2010                   3300            6890          4.55%               7
             Former_USSR_DUMMY Tertiary_enrollment rate Trade Openess
Albania-1990                 0       8.3663600000000002      39.43696
Albania-1991                 0       8.8553300000000004      36.07052
Albania-1992                 0       9.2873199999999994     108.78547
Albania-1993                 0                 11.17761      80.51833
Albania-1994                 0                 10.63358      53.10258
Albania-1995                 0       10.202819999999999      47.61059
Albania-1996                 0       10.939450000000001      44.89543
Albania-1997                 0       12.699719999999999      45.42552
Albania-1998                 0                 13.55017      48.13748
Albania-1999                 0       14.747769999999999      51.01107
Albania-2000                 0                 15.53661      63.45407
Albania-2001                 0       15.904629999999999      66.49105
Albania-2002                 0       16.311430000000001      68.52504
Albania-2003                 0       16.657240000000002      67.02061
Albania-2004                 0       19.890440000000002      67.04723
Albania-2005                 0       23.189830000000001      70.87233
Albania-2006                 0       26.637139999999999      74.26708
Albania-2007                 0                 30.68713      83.20210
Albania-2008                 0       32.092799999999997      77.45175
Albania-2009                 0       33.385550000000002      75.09482
Albania-2010                 0       44.549250000000001      76.54336
Albania-2011                 0       49.878700000000002      81.21856
Albania-2012                 0       59.252009999999999      76.51020
Albania-2013                 0       64.634429999999995      75.87373
Albania-2014                 0       65.782970000000006      75.40787
Albania-2015                 0       62.007620000000003      71.80103
Albania-2016                 0                 58.38185      74.80986
Albania-2017                 0       57.375259999999997      78.16131
Albania-2018                 0       54.961329999999997      77.08240
Armenia-1990                 1       23.204820000000002      81.33572
Armenia-1991                 1                  25.3567     100.86586
Armenia-1992                 1       25.342120000000001     101.07676
Armenia-1993                 1       23.027640000000002     107.97315
Armenia-1994                 1       19.124310000000001     112.42936
Armenia-1995                 1       19.082139999999999      86.11486
Armenia-1996                 1       16.938569999999999      79.22956
Armenia-1997                 1       22.720230000000001      78.54775
Armenia-1998                 1                 33.57358      71.84245
Armenia-1999                 1       35.212409999999998      70.56048
Armenia-2000                 1       35.549790000000002      73.91852
Armenia-2001                 1       33.545299999999997      71.61720
Armenia-2002                 1       36.146859999999997      75.94345
Armenia-2003                 1       37.218879999999999      82.18767
Armenia-2004                 1       37.883139999999997      75.03721
Armenia-2005                 1       39.546770000000002      72.03896
Armenia-2006                 1       43.115349999999999      62.60919
Armenia-2007                 1                 45.93094      58.33645
Armenia-2008                 1       48.489330000000002      55.70286
Armenia-2009                 1       51.334589999999999      58.47887
Armenia-2010                 1       52.989150000000002      66.14731
             natural_resources_pct Tertiary_enrollment_rate_prop log_GNI_PPP
Albania-1990            11.0500298                     0.0836636    7.843849
Albania-1991             9.3448245                     0.0885533    7.533694
Albania-1992            11.4179016                     0.0928732    7.455877
Albania-1993             2.8040945                     0.1117761    7.659171
Albania-1994             1.7381434                     0.1063358    7.745003
Albania-1995             1.2876473                     0.1020282    7.904704
Albania-1996             1.3346144                     0.1093945    8.022897
Albania-1997             1.3700330                     0.1269972    7.930206
Albania-1998             0.3042341                     0.1355017    8.042378
Albania-1999             0.5685413                     0.1474777    8.174703
Albania-2000             1.0947388                     0.1553661    8.289037
Albania-2001             0.7325011                     0.1590463    8.402904
Albania-2002             0.7557640                     0.1631143    8.476371
Albania-2003             0.7620785                     0.1665724    8.546752
Albania-2004             0.7763811                     0.1989044    8.623353
Albania-2005             1.0500847                     0.2318983    8.697847
Albania-2006             1.4310071                     0.2663714    8.817298
Albania-2007             2.1716295                     0.3068713    8.919988
Albania-2008             1.6291992                     0.3209280    9.019180
Albania-2009             0.9800915                     0.3338555    9.067624
Albania-2010             2.0337525                     0.4454925    9.162200
Albania-2011             3.4550441                     0.4987870    9.231123
Albania-2012             3.5961197                     0.5925201    9.254357
Albania-2013             3.5783652                     0.6463443    9.282661
Albania-2014             3.5748966                     0.6578297    9.337854
Albania-2015             1.8132105                     0.6200762    9.375855
Albania-2016             1.0495028                     0.5838185    9.397649
Albania-2017             1.6988592                     0.5737526    9.469623
Albania-2018                    NA                     0.5496133    9.499272
Armenia-1990             0.0000000                     0.2320482    7.757906
Armenia-1991             0.0000000                     0.2535670    7.714231
Armenia-1992             0.1055848                     0.2534212    7.029973
Armenia-1993             0.1026986                     0.2302764    7.081709
Armenia-1994             0.4685675                     0.1912431    7.265430
Armenia-1995             0.7318818                     0.1908214    7.371489
Armenia-1996             0.5112418                     0.1693857    7.489971
Armenia-1997             0.5514971                     0.2272023    7.580700
Armenia-1998             0.1609768                     0.3357358    7.644919
Armenia-1999             0.1414424                     0.3521241    7.696213
Armenia-2000             0.3632039                     0.3554979    7.779049
Armenia-2001             0.2967551                     0.3354530    7.901007
Armenia-2002             0.4600419                     0.3614686    8.051978
Armenia-2003             0.5206733                     0.3721888    8.205218
Armenia-2004             0.9740036                     0.3788314    8.333270
Armenia-2005             0.9012408                     0.3954677    8.511175
Armenia-2006             1.7888617                     0.4311535    8.677610
Armenia-2007             1.2970613                     0.4593094    8.849371
Armenia-2008             1.2945457                     0.4848933    8.948976
Armenia-2009             1.6566356                     0.5133459    8.793309
Armenia-2010             2.9921286                     0.5298915    8.837826
             secondary_attendence_prct
Albania-1990                  90.08174
Albania-1991                  90.89363
Albania-1992                  77.71476
Albania-1993                  70.33512
Albania-1994                  68.72906
Albania-1995                  68.67849
Albania-1996                  67.86755
Albania-1997                  69.36618
Albania-1998                  71.31361
Albania-1999                  71.54467
Albania-2000                  71.07808
Albania-2001                  72.53716
Albania-2002                  72.86855
Albania-2003                  75.24344
Albania-2004                  74.80221
Albania-2005                  77.90939
Albania-2006                  79.18955
Albania-2007                  82.20059
Albania-2008                  84.12509
Albania-2009                  85.69499
Albania-2010                  88.10389
Albania-2011                  89.79816
Albania-2012                  92.28983
Albania-2013                  96.25608
Albania-2014                  97.68487
Albania-2015                  97.38848
Albania-2016                  95.71500
Albania-2017                  95.26589
Albania-2018                  95.43233
Armenia-1990                        NA
Armenia-1991                  92.10371
Armenia-1992                  92.32686
Armenia-1993                  94.74470
Armenia-1994                  96.62907
Armenia-1995                        NA
Armenia-1996                  93.33640
Armenia-1997                  93.23616
Armenia-1998                  80.43603
Armenia-1999                  80.05668
Armenia-2000                  92.15199
Armenia-2001                  88.28202
Armenia-2002                        NA
Armenia-2003                        NA
Armenia-2004                  89.34573
Armenia-2005                  92.05428
Armenia-2006                  94.94133
Armenia-2007                  96.42764
Armenia-2008                  94.97048
Armenia-2009                 100.12562
Armenia-2010                 104.71332
```

and this is my session info

```
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Ireland.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Ireland.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Ireland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    
[5] LC_TIME=English_Ireland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plm_2.2-3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3       pillar_1.4.3     compiler_3.6.2   miscTools_0.6-26 bitops_1.0-6    
 [6] tools_3.6.2      testthat_2.3.1   digest_0.6.23    nlme_3.1-142     lattice_0.20-38 
[11] lifecycle_0.1.0  tibble_2.1.3     gtable_0.3.0     pkgconfig_2.0.3  rlang_0.4.5     
[16] bibtex_0.4.2.2   rstudioapi_0.10  maxLik_1.3-8     swirl_2.4.5      yaml_2.2.0      
[21] dplyr_0.8.4      httr_1.4.1       stringr_1.4.0    lmtest_0.9-37    gbRd_0.4-11     
[26] grid_3.6.2       tidyselect_1.0.0 glue_1.3.1       R6_2.4.1         bdsmatrix_1.3-4 
[31] Rdpack_0.11-1    Formula_1.2-3    ggplot2_3.2.1    purrr_0.3.3      magrittr_1.5    
[36] scales_1.1.0     MASS_7.3-51.4    assertthat_0.2.1 colorspace_1.4-1 sandwich_2.5-1  
[41] stringi_1.4.6    RCurl_1.98-1.1   lazyeval_0.2.2   munsell_0.5.0    crayon_1.3.4    
[46] zoo_1.8-7       
>
```

Comment: could you include an example of your data? (e.g. `dput(head(project_data, 50))`)

Comment: Sure, I did it there but let me know if there's a better way to give a sample

Comment: At least on the subsample you've provided, I do not get your error. So, either it has to do with data not included in your subsample, or it may be some sort of bug in the version of `plm` you have. Can you also [edit] your question to include the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: This link may point you in the right direction: similar error: https://community.rstudio.com/t/invalid-to-set-the-class-to-matrix-unless-the-dimension-attribute-is-of-length-2/27936

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plm()` is expecting a pdata.frame. Your call

```
plm(Y ~ X, data = project_data_panel, model = "within")
```

mixes matrices (Y and X) with pdata.frame (project_data_panel). The correct syntax is

```
plm(log_GNI_PPP ~  EU_application + EU_membership + distance_from_brussels + Former_USSR_DUMMY + natural_resources_pct + secondary_attendence_prct + eu_education_interaction,  data = project_data_panel, model = "within")
```

You still need to check that project_data_panel has all of the required variables.  At least variable called `eu_education_interaction` is missing from the data you included.